# SAS - How to configure sas to use resources from local disk other than local disk C:

Tags: sas

Basically when I do sorting or join table in sas, the sas will use resources / space from local disk C: to process the code, but since I only have 100GB left on local disk C:, It will result in error whenever SAS was out of resources.

My question is how to configure / change the setting in SAS to use resources from Local Disk E: instead, since I have larger space there.

I already looking through the forum, but found no similiar question.

Please Help.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are talking about desktop SAS, or a server that you administer, you can control where the work and utility folders are stored in a few ways.

The best way is to use the `-work` and `-utilloc` options in your `sasv9.cfg` file.  That file can be in a few places, but often the SAS Shortcut you open SAS with specifies it with the `-CONFIG` option.  You can also set the option in that shortcut with `-WORK` or `-UTILLOC` command line options.  The article [How SAS Finds and Processes Configuration Files](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=hostwin&docsetTarget=p0bmj7wjme32ayn1h4wim7trkhp6.htm&locale=en#n126l40y4fx4ymn1gibbxcuicd7x) can help you decide the location of the sasv9.cfg you want to modify; if you are using a personal copy on your own laptop, you may change the one in the Program Files folder, but if not, or if you don 't have administrative rights, you have other places you can place a config file that will override that one.

A paper that discusses a few of these options is one by [Peter Eberhardt and Mengting Wang](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings17/1190-2017.pdf).

Comment: Yes, I change the default 'work' path in the sasv9.cfg, from something like "!windows/temporary" to "E:/temporary"" that did the job. Thanks pal.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to set up a library named `user` for projects that will be time intensive and this way you get it to be dynamic as needed. When you have a library called `user`, **that becomes the default workspace instead of work**. But, you need to clean up that library manually, it won't delete data sets automatically when you're done with it.

```
libname user '/folders/myfolders/demo';
```

As @Tom indicates, you can also set an option to use a library that already exists if desired.

```
options user = myLib;
```

An advantage of this method over the config file method as it only does it for projects where it's needed, rather than your full system.

Comment: Note that the USER system option allows you to use other libref's besides USER for this feature.

Comment: Tried this before, sas will save your work file in defined user library, but still will use resources from local disk C: